# how to use mutiple includes func in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have two lines of code (They are in the same ApplicationRecord file):

```
includes(xxx: :xxx).joins(xxx::xxx).where(options)

includes({xxx: :xxx}, {xxx: :xxx}).where("complex query string")
```

At the first line, the options in where is a hash

At the second line, there is a complex query string in where

If I run it this way, the second result of includes will overwrite the first result

I would like to do a union on the first line and second line results and get the final result, but I cannot figure out how to do it. 
I tried to put the complex query into options, but I dont think rails understands it.
Can anyone tell me what should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use data from `includes` inside `where` because includes doesn't add anything to the query. These are unrelated things. Instead, use `references`. Example:

`User.includes(:posts).where('posts.name = ?', 'example').references(:posts)`

See documentation for details: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes

There are no details to make more detailed answer.